# Was ist 'der zweite Reiter'

Tags: idiom, book

Kürzlich habe ich dieses Krimi namens 'der zweite Reiter' gelesen, [hier verlinkt](https://krimisofa.com/2018/04/23/rezension-alex-beer-der-zweite-reiter-august-emmerich-band-i/). Nachdem ich fertig damit bin, ist mir immer noch nicht klar, was 'der zweite Reiter' bezeichnet. Hat es was mit einer Anspielung auf den Ersten Weltkrieg zu tun? Weil Deutsch nicht meine Muttersprache ist, fällt es mir schwer, zwischen den Zeilen zu lesen.

Könnte jemand Aufschluss darüber geben, falls er/sie es gelesen hat?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about literature, not German language

Comment: Ohne das Buch gelesen zu haben, kann man diese Frage nicht beantworten. Es geht hier also nicht um die deutsche Sprache an sich, sondern ein Buch. Deshalb Off Topic hier.

Comment: @TorstenLink: Die Frage ließe sich evtl. so abändern, dass gefragt wird, ob der "zweite Reiter" eine gängige Redewendung im Deutschen ist (die sich möglicherweise auch im genannten Romantitel wiederfindet). Anderes als der zweite der vier apokalyptischen Reiter will mir aber momentan auch nicht einfallen.

Comment: Von der [Internetseite der Autorin](https://www.alex-beer.com/kontakt-2): "Anregungen, Fragen und Feedback sind jederzeit herzlich willkommen."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Christian culture. After knowing the answer, we can say it doesn't belong here, but it might have been local phrase.

Comment: "the second knight", that is what it means.

Comment: I suppose it means the second musketeer in Fredl Fesl's famous song "Die drei Musketiere" (The Three Musketeers). The second one is the one who carries violets. For reference see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBjpjsZzr4k

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokalyptische_Reiter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es ist keine gängige Redewendung im Deutschen :-)

https://www.lovelybooks.de/autor/Alex-Beer/Der-zweite-Reiter-1416707885-w/ : 
„Der erste Reiter hat die Tyrannei gebracht, der zweite den Krieg, der dritte den Hunger, und wenn Sie mir nix geben, wird bald der vierte kommen.“ „Zu mir allein?“ Emmerich lachte. „Jawohl. Furcht, Niedergang und… „ Sie legte eine theatralische Pause ein. „Und?“ „…Tod.“ Sie berührte mit den Fingerspitzen Emmerichs Bauch. „Sie werden sterben.“ Ihr Blick war so voller Überzeugung, dass ihm das Lachen im Hals stecken blieb. „Oder jemand, der Ihnen nahesteht, wird sein Leben verlieren.“ (Auszug Seite 194)

Ein gutes Buch erklärt sich selbst, oder?

Comment: Dann sind es wohl die apokalyptischen Reiter, wie O.R. Mapper schon spekulierte, und die lassen sich wohl umstandslos übersetzen - aber ein Hinweis auf diese wäre nicht verkehrt, ich meine im Neuen Testament, die sog. Offenbarung d. Johannes, da stammen sie her. Bestimmt gibt es aber ältere Vorbilder dafür.

Comment: Sicher hat die Autorin sich was dabei gedacht, es nicht zu erklären, immerhin ist es der Titel!

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Das ist sehr hilfreich gewesen. Der Zitat muss ich verpasst haben. Im Rückblick ist die Frage ja irrelevant zur Deutsche Sprache, aber ich hätte es nicht gewusst, dass es sich auf die Bibel bezieht.